# Log4net LoggerMatchFilter - How to filter only in "match whole word" case?

Tags: c#, .net, filter, log4net, log4net-appender

I'm using the Log4net LoggerMatchFilter to log info only from certain class.
The thing is that the loggerToMatch property is using `StartsWith(string)` to compare and as result I get logs also from classes that their name begin with the name of my desired class.
My config contains somthing like that:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />      
    <loggerToMatch value="Class.Name.Space.MyClassName" /> 
    </filter>  
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

In the log I get also lines from classes like:
Class.Name.Space.MyClassName123

Is there a way to filter with "match whole word" condition?
(My code is c# .Net 3.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement such a `Filter` by eg. inheriting from [`LoggerMatchFilter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Filter_LoggerMatchFilter.htm) so you can reuse some features, while you override the matching algorithm using a full equality comparison instead; `loggingEvent.LoggerName == this.LoggerToMatch`.

Borrowing from Log4net's code, this looks like:

```
namespace PFX.Logging
{
    public class LoggerFullMatchFilter : log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter
    {
        public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            if (loggingEvent == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");
            }

            if (this.LoggerToMatch != null 
                && this.LoggerToMatch.Length != 0 
                && loggingEvent.LoggerName == this.LoggerToMatch
                )
            {
                if (this.AcceptOnMatch)
                {
                    return FilterDecision.Accept;
                }

                return FilterDecision.Deny;
            }

            return FilterDecision.Neutral;
        }
    }
}
```

You use this custom filter in your configuration as shown below,
specifying its fully qualified assembly name (*namespace.class, assembly*)

```
<filter type="PFX.Logging.LoggerFullMatchFilter, Lib">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <loggerToMatch value="Class.Name.Space.MyClassName" />
</filter>
```